# Debugging a Scrollbar code that's not working properly on Blogger

Tags: html, css, blogger

I've been trying to get this scrollbar code to work on Blogger, but haven't been able to figure out how to. Can someone see if they are able to figure out what the issue is, and how to resolve it.

**Same Code,** Both look and act different,

Jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/xuc92tt3/

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ee5bt.png)

**vs.**

Blogger:

https://debugscroll.blogspot.com/

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EwZa.png)

Also, there shouldn't be a horizontal line below the div blocks either.

```html
<style>
      .test {
        width: 266px;
        height: 175px;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        overflow: auto;
        background: #000;
        list-style: none;
        text-align: left;
      }
      
      .test li {
        padding-bottom: 20px;
      }
      
      .test li:last-of-type {
        padding: 0;
      }
      
      h2 {
        margin: 0;
        line-height: 1;
        font-size: 25px;
        color: #00f;
      }
      
      .test a:link {
        width: 243px;
        height: 20px;
        display: block;
        background: green;
      }
      
      .test a:visited {
        background: #f00;
        color: #000000;
      }
      
      .test a:hover {
        color: #000;
      }
    
    </style>
    
    
    <ul class="test ">
      <li>
        <h2>Text</h2>
        <a href="#" target="blank"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h2>Text</h2>
        <a href="#" target="blank"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h2>Text</h2>
        <a href="#" target="blank"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h2>Text</h2>
        <a href="#" target="blank"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h2>Text</h2>
        <a href="#" target="blank"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h2>Text</h2>
        <a href="#" target="blank"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h2>Text</h2>
        <a href="#" target="blank"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h2>Text</h2>
        <a href="#" target="blank"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h2>Text</h2>
        <a href="#" target="blank"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h2>Text</h2>
        <a href="#" target="blank"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h2>Text</h2>
        <a href="#" target="blank"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h2>Text</h2>
        <a href="#" target="blank"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h2>Text</h2>
        <a href="#" target="blank"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h2>Text</h2>
        <a href="#" target="blank"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like in the blogspot example your `<li>` elements are inheriting a 15px padding from a global style declared in the page head section.

Try overriding that with the following css:

```
.test li {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: I just put that in, it didn't do anything. It had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS code

```
.main-inner .widget ul li {
    padding: 0;
    border-top: 0;
    border-bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.main-inner .widget h2 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: That didn't work either, all that did was remove the scrollbar completely which is what I don't want to happen.

Comment: I think you meant: overflow-x: hidden;

Comment: That works with removing the horizontal scroll. But the text and block are not in the right spot.

Comment: What else needs to be adjusted so that the blogger one looks like the js fiddle one? https://i.imgur.com/QArHHwL.png